# Trying to build nuget package with VS 2017 Team Explorer installed

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I installed the VS 2017 TeamExplorer which added a separate VS 2017 install folder. Now when I try to build a nuget package, I get an error saying

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.CSha
>   rp.CurrentVersion.targets

So it appears now it is trying to use MSBuild from the TeamExplorer install path instead of the Enterprise path.

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.3.409.57025' from
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.

Is there a way to make the original path (Enterprise) the default for MSBuild?

Comment: See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2460) that links to this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260114/microsoft-csharp-core-targets-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I will mark this as the answer until a better solution comes along!

---

This isn't a **GOOD** answer but I uninstalled the VS 2017 Team Explorer and it now works properly. I still would like to know how we can control this.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. BTW, why you install the team explorer? I guess you should already installed the Visual Studio 2017? AFAIK, the team explorer ship as a part of Visual Studio, we do not need to install it when we have the  VS installed.

Comment: There was a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2460) opened so I wouldn't mark it as answer yet or update in the future..

Comment: @Leo-MSFT, I installed Team Explorer to get the TeamFoundation assemblies I needed for writing custom console app to query TFS 2010, which worked, Also our company wants to test installing Team Explorer for non-developers and I installed it as a test but my main reason was the TFS client assemblies for the API.

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer until a better solution comes along.